# How to divide a given time interval into equal intervals?

Tags: python

Given an interval of time:

```
a = [20,40]
```

I need to covert it into an equal intervals of:

```
a = [[20,30],[30,40]]
```

I tried this code:

```
v1 = a[0]; v2 = a[1]
d.append(v1)
val = abs(v1-v2)
n = int(val/2)
for i in range(n):
     v1 += n
     d.append(v1)
print d
```

Can anyone suggest a code to do this it will be helpfull

Comment: This is the 4th time you ask "so if anyone can suggest a way to do this in python, it will be helpful". Obviously, spoon-feeding you code is not helpful at all.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 1):

I can point out a few incorrect things of what you've tried, instead of writing out the code for you.

```
for i in range(n):
     v1 += n
     d.append(v1)
```

Remember, from your example n is set to 10. So when you say for i in range(n), you will be iterating through your for loop 10 times.

And if you look at the way you append to d, this will not be appending a smaller list to a overall list. This will keep appending all numbers to just one list.

I'm guessing this is the output you are currently getting: [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120].

With what I said, give it another shot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the first part by calculating an interval and using a loop to create a tuple in each iteration using that interval. This will give an answer corresponding to the desired result you listed.

However, notice that in your example the end of the previous tuple is the same to the start of the next. If you don't want them to intersect, then you need to a similar logic to the first, but do + 1 at the right time.

Here is some code, the first using a for loop and the second using a post test loop:

```
def interval_divide(min, max, intervals):
   assert intervals != 0
   interval_size = round((max - min) / intervals)
   result = []
   start = min
   for start in range(min, max, interval_size):
      end = start + interval_size
      result.append([start, end])
   return result

a = [20, 40]
print("1 intervals", interval_divide(a[0], a[1], 1))
print("2 intervals", interval_divide(a[0], a[1], 2))
print("3 intervals", interval_divide(a[0], a[1], 3))
print("4 intervals", interval_divide(a[0], a[1], 4))

def interval_divide2(min, max, intervals):
   assert intervals != 0
   interval_size = round((max - min) / intervals)
   result = []
   start = min
   end = min + interval_size
   while True:
      result.append([start, end])
      start = end + 1
      end = end + interval_size
      if len(result) == intervals:
         break
   return result

print("-----")
print("1 intervals", interval_divide2(a[0], a[1], 1))
print("2 intervals", interval_divide2(a[0], a[1], 2))
print("3 intervals", interval_divide2(a[0], a[1], 3))
print("4 intervals", interval_divide2(a[0], a[1], 4))
```

The results will as follows:

```
$ python3 intervals.py 
1 intervals [[20, 40]]
2 intervals [[20, 30], [30, 40]]
3 intervals [[20, 27], [27, 34], [34, 41]]
4 intervals [[20, 25], [25, 30], [30, 35], [35, 40]]
-----
1 intervals [[20, 40]]
2 intervals [[20, 30], [31, 40]]
3 intervals [[20, 27], [28, 34], [35, 41]]
4 intervals [[20, 25], [26, 30], [31, 35], [36, 40]]
```

Note that when we are using three intervals the end doesn't terminate properly. This is because we cannot divide 20 by 3 with no reminder, and thus its not possible to have all the intervals of the same size.

We can still improve our answer though by removing the rounding when we calculate the interval as follows (and still keep the result in integer terms):

```
def interval_divide(min, max, intervals):
   assert intervals != 0
   interval_size = (max - min) / intervals
   result = []
   start = min
   end = start + interval_size
   while True:
       result.append([int(start), int(end)])
       start = end
       end = end + interval_size
       if len(result) == intervals:
          break
   return result

def interval_divide2(min, max, intervals):
   assert intervals != 0
   interval_size = (max - min) / intervals
   result = []
   start = min
   end = min + interval_size
   while True:
      result.append([int(start), int(end)])
      start = end + 1
      end = end + interval_size
      if len(result) == intervals:
         break
   return result
```

The new answers are:

```
1 intervals [[20, 40]]
2 intervals [[20, 30], [30, 40]]
3 intervals [[20, 26], [26, 33], [33, 40]]
4 intervals [[20, 25], [25, 30], [30, 35], [35, 40]]
-----
1 intervals [[20, 40]]
2 intervals [[20, 30], [31, 40]]
3 intervals [[20, 26], [27, 33], [34, 40]]
4 intervals [[20, 25], [26, 30], [31, 35], [36, 40]]
```

The three intervals are still not fully equal, but pretty close without displaying the answer using decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
import numpy as np

points = np.linspace(20, 40, num=2+1)
intervals = np.array([points[:-1], points[1:]]).transpose()
print(intervals)
```

and get a np.array:

```
[[20. 30.]
 [30. 40.]]
```

Of course, for

```
points = np.linspace(10, 40, num=6+1)
intervals = np.array([points[:-1], points[1:]]).transpose()
print(intervals)
```

we have

```
[[10. 15.]
 [15. 20.]
 [20. 25.]
 [25. 30.]
 [30. 35.]
 [35. 40.]]
```